# Main menu on game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I have created a menu for my game with buttons and whatnot as a separate .fla file named Menu. My actual game is another .fla file called Game.fla. I was wondering what the best way would be of loading this menu before the game plays?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a .swc with your Menu.fla, and then just add that .swc to your  Game.fla

If you are using CS6, make sure that you are setting linkage for any MovieClips you want to create instances of in your code.

In the actionscript settings on the library path tab, you can add a .swc that will be included into your .swf when compiling.

In your code, you can now create an instance and add to the display list :

```
// Assuming MainMenu was a movieclip with linkage set in your .swc 
var mainMenu:MainMenu = new MainMenu;
addChild(mainMenu);
```

I should note that this does not load the .swc at runtime, it includes the .swc to your .swf  at compile time. I would recommend this method over loading a .swf in most cases. Cases where I might not, is if there was a large amount of content that wasn't needed all at once. That would allow you to minimize the amount of memory you were using and reduce the .swf size of your main .swf so it loads quicker.

Anytime you are loading .swf's in at runtime you are adding another layer of complexity, so I'd not recommend it unless you do have a good reason to do so. From what you have described, this doesn't sound like a situation where I'd load an external .swf at runtime.

Comment: OK, I created the .swc file but how do I add it and get it to display before the game?

Comment: I do have Adobe Flash CS6 yes

Comment: I edited my answer with the code to use an instance from that .swc

Comment: Ah, I see. I managed to get the menu to display but the score, timer, crosshairs and enemy ships are still there on the screen (As though they're 'on top' of the menu). I put the code snippet you gave an example of at the top of the code in the Main.as file (First lines of code inside the `public function Main(){` part.

Comment: Yes, it's up to you to decide how to layer things :) , I am just telling you how to use a .swc in your other fla.

Comment: That's another question, this one has been answered. Just addChild(mainMenu) AFTER your ships etc. Right ? either way, this question is not about managing the display list.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this Flash game will be a Facebook game/app. I assume the .swc stuff will still work?

Comment: why wouldn't it ? The result or your compile is a .swf file, regardless of whether or not you are adding a .swc to your project. Again -- You are NOT loading it at run-time, it's compiled into your .swf

Comment: I want to add event listeners to the buttons on the menu so that they actually do things when they are clicked. Would it be better to continue the trend and create a Menu.as file, put the AS3 code in there then publish it as a .swc? Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Load the swf output from Menu.fla and keep a check on the progressEvent from loader. Don't show the game screen until Menu.swf is completely loaded and initialized.

Some more details wrt comment from OP:
You can you http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#load%28%29 to load external swfs. init Event would mark that the swf's actionscript has started executing. OTOH, complete event would tell that all the swf bytes have been loaded.

Comment: Sorry, how do you do that?

Comment: added some more info to the answer.

Comment: You haven't addChild'ed the loader. Also, you don't seem to be listening for events from loader... that might be fine, but without listening to events, your game would start before main.swf is loaded and shown.